# How to rearrange order of block elements in responsive designs?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have the following HTML markup,

```
<section class="container about-container">
            <div class="about-author col col-2-3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab nesciunt voluptatum sunt explicabo similique quam tempora fugiat laborum aliquid cupiditate, earum quo, pariatur voluptates delectus corporis quos et vero quia.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="image-author col col-1-3"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x280" alt="sudipto-das"></div>
</section>
```

and have the following styles defined,

```
.col {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
   }

.col-2-3 {
    width: 66%;
   }

   .col-1-3 {
    width: 33%;
   }
```

fiddle can be found here, https://jsfiddle.net/yh76h0f9/
Now I would like to make this section responsive, but when I set the col to display: block, the image naturally flows below the text. How can the image be brought above the text when the screen size is 570px and below?

Answer (score 0):

Change the direction of the `section` and change the order of children:

```css
.container{
direction: rtl;
}

.col {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
   }

.col-2-3 {
    width: 66%;
    direction: ltr;
   }

   .col-1-3 {
    width: 33%;
   }
   
   .col-1-3 img {
   max-width: 100%;
   }
```

```html
<section class="container about-container">
<div class="image-author col col-1-3"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x280" alt="sudipto-das"></div>
            <div class="about-author col col-2-3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab nesciunt voluptatum sunt explicabo similique quam tempora fugiat laborum aliquid cupiditate, earum quo, pariatur voluptates delectus corporis quos et vero quia.</p>
            </div>            
</section>
```

And I added an style for image max width.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use flexbox here; `flex-direction:column-reverse` will do what you want:

```css
.container {display:flex}

@media screen and (max-width:570px) {
    /* small screens */
    .container {flex-direction: column-reverse}
}

@media screen and (min-width:570px) {
    /* large screens */
    .container {flex-direction: row}
    /* adjust sizes of child elements as needed, with % or flex-grow */
}
```

```html
<section class="container about-container">
            <div class="about-author col col-2-3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab nesciunt voluptatum sunt explicabo similique quam tempora fugiat laborum aliquid cupiditate, earum quo, pariatur voluptates delectus corporis quos et vero quia.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="image-author col col-1-3"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x280" alt="sudipto-das"></div>
</section>
```

(View the snippet at "full page" to be able to resize it and see the "small screen" version)

Comment: well, the reason I did not use the flex display was that of the compatibility issues with older IE browsers, how can I provide a workaround for this scenario?

Comment: Not easily, I'm afraid, unless you want to resort to tricks like `rtl`.  Personally I'd use this as an opportunity to exercise the phrase "degrades gracefully in older browsers".

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past to overcome this is include the same image twice. In this situation one above text for mobile and one below text for desktop. Then use your media queries to show/ hide whichever one according to your screen size.

```css
.col {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.col-2-3 {
 width: 66%;
}

.col-1-3 {
 width: 33%;
}
.mobile-image{
 display:none;
 }
@media all and (max-width:570px){
.mobile-image{
 display:block;
} 
.desktop-image{
  display:none;
}
}
```

```html
<section class="container about-container">
    <div class="image-author mobile-image col col-1-3"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x280" alt="sudipto-das"></div>
    <div class="about-author col col-2-3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab nesciunt voluptatum sunt explicabo similique quam tempora fugiat laborum aliquid cupiditate, earum quo, pariatur voluptates delectus corporis quos et vero quia.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-author desktop-image col col-1-3"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x280" alt="sudipto-das"></div>
</section>
```